# TMTumblrSDK for iOS user login

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, tumblr

My app need to add user tumblr account, when user click "add account" then pop up a page (NOT jump out to Tumblr app or open safari tumblr web page.) the page opens IN my app

[image]

, and then with a delegate to let me know whether user allow read and write access to the tumblr account.

How to implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To do the authorisation of tumblr inside the application itself, use TumblrShare library.
here is the link [TumblrShare GIT](https://github.com/lucianboboc/TumblrShare)